# trouble with Google API's?

Tags: ios, api, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have been running google maps and google places API in my app for about a year now. I woke up today and was not able to use the map which was greyed out, or searches. In the console,

ERROR AUTO COMPLETE Error Domain=com.google.places.ErrorDomain Code=-4 "Operation failed due to an invalid (malformed or missing) API key. See the developer's guide (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/start) for information on creating and using an API key." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Operation failed due to an invalid (malformed or missing) API key. See the developer's guide (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/start) for information on creating and using an API key., NSUnderlyingError=0x283e81560 {Error Domain=com.google.places.api.server.ErrorDomain Code=-2 "REQUEST_DENIED" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend?project=_, NSLocalizedDescription=REQUEST_DENIED}}}

The thing is all of my API's are called in the right place and I have been able to use maps for a while. Why all of a sudden it stops working?

Answer (score 0):

Recently Google announced the new version of Places SDK client and deprecated the previous one. I believe you should migrate to new version asap, because the deprecated version will stop working very soon.

The new Places SDK client requires that you enable Places API web service in your Cloud project. The error message `This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend?project=_,`  refers to the Places API web service.

Double check if the Places API web service is enabled, API key created and billing account configured properly.

The official documentation has the following statement

> To use the Places SDK for iOS, you must:
>
> - Include an API key with all API requests.
> - Enable billing on each of your projects.
> - Enable the Places API service for each of your projects

For further details have a look at migration guide:
https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help! my app is still in test mode, so I do not want to be build for playing around. I did not create a billing account. would this cause errors?

Comment: Also @xomena would that cause my maps to be grey?

Comment: Something should have changed with when/how you provide the API key. Long time ago Google SDK would crash your app at an attempt to use the map without the key, nowadays they show you en empty map. You should review when/how do you provide your map SDK key to them. I checked Google maps in my apps and they work alright, no change from Google I'd say.

Comment: Billing account is mandatory for Google Maps Platform since July 2018, but typically grey map is caused by the wrong API key or wrong restrictions set on API key.